# android invoke another apk and get a return result

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity

I am integrating two different APKs whose logic is pretty simple:

App A calls App B passing an amount
App B receives the request
If App B's "active" activity is currently in (main) Activity C
    set the amount
    allow the user to process the amount
    once done processing return a transaction number to App A
Else 
    return an RESULT_CANCELED to App A

Given this I can certainly can call App B via startActivityForResult, but:

1. What happens in App B when the (main) Activity C is launched when the application was left sitting in Activity D?  How do I detect I was in the middle of Activity D in order to fail and  return RESULT_CANCELED?
2. In normal processing I want to return the resulting transaction number to the caller, I've tried passing an Intent with extras in setResult, but the intent is always returned to App A as null.

Does someone have a simple example of this?

Answer (score 1):

You can only use `startActivityForResult()` if both the calling activity and the called activity run **in the same task**. Otherwise `startActivityForResult()` will generate an immediate call to `onActivityResult()` with `RESULT_CANCELED`.

Given the above premise, if App A starts App B using `startActivityForResult()`, this will always create a new instance of the App B's main activity, and therefore it is not possible for App B to be in any other state.

If the 2 apps are running in different tasks, then you will need to communicate between them using other mechanisms (broadcast intents, background services, shared files, or something similar).